# Configure PyCharm to work with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, pycharm, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I have django-cookiecutter template setup with docker & docker-composer.
It comes with preconfigured django management commands (runserver, migrate, etc.)

When I'm trying to use any of those I get the following:

```
ad381d177c42:python -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py test . /app
Testing started at 2:17 ...
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/environ/environ.py:608: UserWarning: /app/config/settings/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one.
  "environment separately, create one." % env_file)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:248: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the default database instead.
  RuntimeWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The `docker-compose up` working very well.

Here is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data_dev: {}
  postgres_backup_dev: {}

services:
  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_dev:/backups
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=budger

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile-dev
    command: /start-dev.sh
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=budger
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres
      - mailhog

  pycharm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile-dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=budger
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - postgres

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
```

PyCharm interpreter configuration:

[`django docker-compose` service interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW7tY.png)

[`pycharm docker-compose` service interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RcRN.png)

Once again, everything seems working like a charm but not in PyCharm :(

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the source of the problem.
Entrypoint is ignored by PyCharm 2016.3.2.

[Ticket on Jetbrains bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21709)

Reverting PyCharm to 2016.2.3 makes everything work.

Comment: I have updated the PyCharm to the latest version (2016.3.2) and it works, it appears they have fixed the issue.